# How is Cache-Control: max-age affected by intermediate caching?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cache-control

I am currently serving an HTML page to users with a `Cache-Control: max-age=600` header. I believe this allows the users' browsers to cache the page for a maximum of 10 minutes.

I am considering adding a CDN in front of my server which, due to the above header, should also cache the page for a maximum of 10 minutes.

If a user obtains the page when it has been in the CDN cache for 9 minutes, say, will it still be cached in the browser for 10 minutes, giving a total cached time of 19 minutes? Or will it only be cached in the browser for 1 minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic approaches here.

The CDN may decide that it is an HTTP cache, as defined by [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234). In that case, it must add an [`Age`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.1) header to every response that it serves from cache (without contacting your server). It must also **keep** the [`Date`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.2) header sent by your server. This enables a downstream cache (such as the browser’s cache) to determine for how much *more* time it can cache the response.

For example, if your server sends:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.12
Date: Sun, 15 May 2016 16:51:31 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
```

then the cache might send:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.12
Date: Sun, 15 May 2016 16:51:31 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Age: 541
Via: 1.1 mycdn
```

This approach is used, for example, by [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) and by [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) (and thus by [Fastly](https://www.fastly.com/blog/benefits-using-varnish)). Sometimes, caches get it wrong: [until a couple years ago](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/commit/89870e0bbd785964c322e1e453f492d747731c88), Varnish would erroneously reset the `Date` header on cached responses. In my experiments, though, Firefox and Chrome do not seem to be confused by this (because `Age` is still there).

Alternatively, the CDN may decide that it’s an HTTP *origin server*, and cooperate with your server by its *own* rules. In that case, it must **not** add an `Age` header, and it must **reset** the `Date` header—but then it can also do whatever it wants to the other headers, including `Cache-Control`. For example, it can decrement the `max-age` by the number of seconds that the object spent in its cache:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: MyCDN/1.2.3
Date: Sun, 15 May 2016 17:00:32 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=59
```

But it may not even do this, as generally caching is most useful for static content, which is usually versioned and cached “forever.” Thus, for example, whenever you request `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js` (served by [MaxCDN](https://www.maxcdn.com/)), it comes with the same `max-age=315360000` and an `Expires` far in the future.

So you will probably need to check how your particular CDN handles this.

Comment: A very informative answer, thank you. I was looking at some pages served via CloudFront and was surprised that `max-age` was not decreasing (as in your second approach). I did not notice that `Age` was increasing instead.